# How to Access Return Value of $fetch server side Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, fetch-api, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to use Nuxt3 $fetch server side to write to a database. I'm using prisma to access the database. When I use $fetch, I want the endpoint to return a "success" string back to my component so I can present it to the user on the UI. When I try to console log *answer* to check if it is "success", it is undefined. Am I not returning properly in the API or should I be using a different function such as useFetch?

Component Function:

```
async pushToDatabase() {
  for (const row of this.information) {
    if (row.data.firstName != "" && row.data.lastName != "") {
      const { answer } = await $fetch("/api/addRow", {
        method: "POST",
        body: row,
      });
      console.log(answer);
    }
  }
},
```

API handler:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body = await readBody(event);
  const info = body.data as IAttendeeData;
  console.log(body);
  await prisma.test
    .create({
      data: {
        firstName: info.firstName,
        lastName: info.lastName,
        age: info.age,
        gender: info.gender,
      },
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("write worked");
      return "success";
    })
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
      console.log("failed write");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are [desctructering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment?retiredLocale=de) the response to the property `anwser`. Are you sure your response contains that kind of data? Try to show full the response:

```
      const response = await $fetch("/api/addRow", {
        method: "POST",
        body: row,
      });
      console.log(response );
```

Comment: I tried what is above, but it console logs undefined.